# SQLite parameter binding fails with nested query

Tags: sqlite

I have the following query

```sql
DELETE FROM Item WHERE rowid IN (
  SELECT rowid FROM ItemFts WHERE path = :path
)
```

where `ItemFts` is a FTS5 table that uses the `Item` table as its external content. My observation is that the query executed but the record was not deleted. I have confirmed that the following two queries both work individually:

This returns the correct rowid (e.g. `1`):

```sql
SELECT rowid FROM Item WHERE path = :path
```

This correctly deletes the record at `rowid = 1`:

```sql
DELETE FROM Item WHERE rowid IN (1)
```

My issue happens when I nest the two queries. For additional context, I'm using the `exec` method from [SQLite's wasm OO API](https://sqlite.org/wasm/doc/trunk/api-oo1.md#db-exec).
So the binding looks like this

```js
db.exec(`
DELETE FROM Item WHERE rowid IN (
  SELECT rowid FROM ItemFts WHERE path = :path
)
`, {bind: {":path": "some/path"}})
```

My main question is that I couldn't tell if the issue is in my code or its a problem with the wasm library. Could any SQLite expert help me? Thank you!

UPDATE

Hard coded path also works, so the issue is most likely in the binding.

```sql
DELETE FROM Item WHERE rowid IN (
  SELECT rowid FROM ItemFts WHERE path = 'some/hard/coded/path'
)
```

UPDATE 2

A workaround for anyone encountering the same issue

```js
db.transaction(() => {
  const rowids = db.selectValues("SELECT rowid FROM ItemFts WHERE path = :path", {
    ":path": path,
  });

  db.exec(`DELETE FROM Item WHERE rowid IN (${rowids.join(",")})`);
});
```

Comment: does the query work if you hardcode the value instead of binding it?

Comment: One other thing to try is the nested query with a literal constant path rather than the bound value. If that works, you know it's the binding that's failing, not the SQL itself.

Comment: Hard coded value works. I have updated the example.

Comment: Since this feels like a bug in the SQLite wasm library, I have also started a thread in the SQLite forum: https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/40ce55bdf5. I will post updates as soon as there is progress.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the issue was due to my careless use the API. I used this:

```js
db.exec(`...`, {":path": path})
```

Instead of this:

```js
db.exec(`...`, { bind: {":path": path} })
```

Apparently, I had confused `db.exec` with `db.selectObjects`, which has a shallower signature for parameter binding.